# Is it safe to iterate a dereferenced vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
std::vector<int>* someVector;
// Initialize vector here and add elements
//****
// Now loop vector after initializing it
for (int val : *someVector)
 {
     doSomething(val);
 }
```

In the above example, is it safe to iterate a vector like that?

Comment: What do you mean "like that"? In the given code, `someVector` is never initialized so dereferencing it is undefined behavior. Do you mean "initialize vector" includes making the pointer valid (actually point to a vector)?

Comment: I'm  going to guess that the OP is trying to ask whether `someVector` can get reassigned while the iteration takes place, and what effect it has on the iteration. I see that "Initialize vector" has been commented out, so there's probably a chunk of initialization code that that properly sets `someVector` to point to an appropriate vector.

Comment: @Sam Let's be honest before starting wild guesses. The question is unclear and the OP is missing to provide an a [MCVE]. Voted to close.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with harmless wild guesses, as long as they are properly disclaimed as such.

Comment: @Sam I didn't mean you are wrong with your guess, but the OP is with their question as asked atm.

Comment: Not safe if `doSomething` inserts to the vector

Comment: Its unlikely you would need a pointer to a vector (or any std container). Usually they are passed around by reference or their data is *moved* to where it needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

The dereference is not the issue here,

```
std::vector<int>* v = new std::vector<int>;
v->push_back(1);
for (int val : *v) {
}
```

the above code is perfectly fine, however the code you've shown doesn't indicate whether `someVector` was ever initialized or if it was maybe deinitialized.

The question is really whether or not the pointer is valid. If you know the pointer is valid, then dereferencing it is fine, whether it's a vector, a list, a map or an integer.

```
std::vector<int>* v = new std::vector<int>;
v->push_back(1);
delete v;
for (int val : *v) {
}
```

The code will compile and possibly run, but what it does is completely Undefined Behavior.

So "is it safe": there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

> In the above example, is it safe to iterate a vector like that?

No, it isn't.

Before entering that loop, you obviously should check that at least

```
someVector != nullptr
```

and ensure it was initialized correctly after declaration.

Or even better initialize the pointer directly.

```
std::vector<int>* someVector = new std::vector<int>();
```

---

The better question would be, why a `std::vector<int>*` pointer is used there at all?

Comment: And the answer to that question is equally hard to determine, but likely masochism.